# using jython and open office 2.4 to convert docs to pdf

Tags: python, jython, openoffice.org

I completed a python script using pyuno which successfully converted a document/ xls / rtf etc to a pdf.
Then I needed to update a mssql database, due to open office currently supporting python 2.3, it's ancientness, lacks support for decent database libs. So I have resorted to using Jython, this way im not burdened down by running inside OO python environment using an old pyuno.

This also means that my conversion code is broken, and I need to now make use of the java libraries instead of the pyuno libs.

> import com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue as PropertyValue
> import com.sun.star.bridge.XUnoUrlResolver as XUnoUrlResolver
> import com.sun.star.comp.helper.Bootstrap as Bootstrap
> ->> import com.sun.star.frame.XComponentLoader as XComponentLoader
> ->> import com.sun.star.frame.XStorable as XStorable
> import com.sun.star.lang.XMultiComponentFactory as XMultiComponentFactory
> import com.sun.star.uno.UnoRuntime as UnoRuntime
> import com.sun.star.uno.XComponentContext as XComponentContext

The includes with the '->>' do not import the compiler does not recognise the com.sun.star.frame cant see the 'frame' bit. These are the libs I have included.

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/eda5cda76d.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/eda5cda76d.jpg)

Some advice on this matter would be well received

> context = XComponentContext
> xMultiCompFactory = XMultiComponentFactory
> xcomponentloader = XComponentLoader
>
> //used in python
> ctx = None
> smgr = None
> doc = None
> url = None
>
> context = Bootstrap.bootstrap()
> xMultiCompFactory = self.context.getServiceManager()
> xcomponentloader = UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XComponentLoader.class,  ....xMultiCompFactory.createInstanceWithContext("com.sun.star.frame.Desktop", context))
>
> file = "file:\\" + file
> // also what is the equivalent of url = uno.systemPathToFileUrl(file) in Java so that I can make use of it to nicely format my path
> properties = []
> p = PropertyValue()
> p.Name = "Hidden"
> p.Value = True
> properties.append(p)
> properties = tuple(properties)
> doc = xcomponentloader.loadComponentFromURL(file, "_blank",0, properties)

Answer (score 1):

And so it goes, according to this guy, you need some oil.... and it works like a charm

http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.phtml?p=304263#304263

include this lib C:\OpenOffice_24\program\classes\unoil.jar

Comment: open office guys beat you all.

Comment: Thank god at least someone uses and understands that pile of "dog regurgitation".

Answer (score 0):

Using Jython is a great idea for this I think. But why could you not use two scripts, one with pyuno/2.3 and one with pymssql/2.5 (or whatever db adapter you are using)?.

The intermediate format could be anything like a pickle, or json, or XML.

Edit: I should add that I have used pyuno quite extensively, and I feel your pain.

Comment: Great idea! but as it is company policy to write Java! Sneaking python is a little dodgy, what I say is: I run it on the JVM, what else could it be!? *smirk* then swear cause the job isnt going as smooth as it should, for me to convince others that python really is something to look at seriously

Comment: So all you happy hacker python jython people! I was hopeing for an answer! Wonder if the open office guys will beat you!?

Comment: Seriously, pyuno has the number "666" imprinted on it.

Comment: Even more seriously, isn't the oo.org Java integration much better than the python integration? It should be, a load of functionality of oo itself is in Java.

Comment: yeah, that is why i chose to hop over to jython, giving me access to those libs! ... this is the sad pile of dog regurgitation i have come up with.